# netsh "The system cannot find the file specified." from the prompt

Tags: netsh

C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface show interface

```
Admin State  = Disabled
State = Disconnected 
Type = Dedicated
Interface Name = Ethernet 2
```

C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet 2" admin=Enabled

The system cannot find the file specified.